# Multipiping in C

Tags: pipe, fork

I am trying to implement a program in such a way: So I have a parent process and N child processes. I want to make N pipes. Write side(fd[1]) of pipes' will be parent process's stdout and Read side**s** of pipes' will be stdin of child processes'. The problem is that when I write smth to pipe all children processes get that message from pipes. But I want to send messages individually to specific child, i.e. only that child will get message through its pipe others won't get. I got stuck can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your problem is the following: the parent process has only one stdout, yet you say that "write side of pipes" will be the stdout of parent process. Don't you recognise that there are multiple write side file descriptors if you have multiple pipes? But there's only one stdout of the parent process.

Your only option is to drop the requirement that the stdout of parent process will write to a child, because what child would it write then if you have multiple children? You can simply use multiple pipe file descriptors. If you have

```
int pipefd[5][2];
```

then you can call

```
pipe(pipefd[0]);
pipe(pipefd[1]);
pipe(pipefd[2]);
pipe(pipefd[3]);
pipe(pipefd[4]);
```

and write to a specific child process by using pipefd[N][1] where N is the id of the child process. Be sure to use dup2() to duplicate the read side of the correct pipe read file descriptor to the stdin of the child process.

Do note that you really need to create multiple pipes. Your question is somewhat unclear, but it seems that you have just one pipe and all children read from that same pipe. This might explain why all children processes get the same message.